# XSLT 2.0 Error checking type of the expression

Tags: java, xslt, xslt-2.0

XSLT 2.0

I have an email which is stored in a document DB and denoted below as travEmail, I am trying to do a check to see if the lowercase travEmail starts with the lowercase search query, denoted as lowerSearchQuery below, and if the check is successful then the document will be added to the response

```
    <xsl:variable name="searchQuery" select = "/response/lst/lst/str[@name = 'q']" >
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="searchQueryAfter" select = "substring-after($searchQuery,'email:')" >
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="lowercase">abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="uppercase">ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ</xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="lowerSearchQuery" select="translate($searchQueryAfter, $uppercase, $lowercase)">
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:variable name="travEmail" select="arr[@name='email']/str"> 
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="lowerEmail" select="translate($travEmail, $uppercase, $lowercase)"> 
    </xsl:variable>
```

the below code which checks if email starts with lowerSearchQuery compiles and works as intended:

```
<xsl:if test="not(position() > $retLimit) and arr[@name='email']/str [starts-with(.,$lowerSearchQuery)]">
```

but does not work in cases where email in the document DB is not stored as lowercase, when i translate the email to lowercase and compare to the lowercase search query

```
<xsl:if test="not(position() > $retLimit) and $lowerEmail [starts-with(.,$lowerSearchQuery)]">
```

i get the below compilation error 'Error checking type of the expression'

```
Caused by: javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException: Error checking type of the expression 'filter-expr(variable-ref(lowerEmail/string), [pred(funcall(starts-with, [step("self", -1), variable-ref(lowerSearchQuery/string)]))])'.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl.newTemplates(TransformerFactoryImpl.java:988)
    at org.apache.camel.builder.xml.XsltBuilder.setTransformerSource(XsltBuilder.java:360)
    at org.apache.camel.component.xslt.XsltEndpoint.loadResource(XsltEndpoint.java:334)
    at org.apache.camel.component.xslt.XsltEndpoint.doStart(XsltEndpoint.java:388)
    at org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:61)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.startService(DefaultCamelContext.java:3232)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doAddService(DefaultCamelContext.java:1212)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.addService(DefaultCamelContext.java:1173)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.addService(DefaultCamelContext.java:1169)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.getEndpoint(DefaultCamelContext.java:586)
    ... 61 more
Caused by: Error checking type of the expression 'filter-expr(variable-ref(lowerEmail/string), [pred(funcall(starts-with, [step("self", -1), variable-ref(lowerSearchQuery/string)]))])'.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.compiler.FilterExpr.typeCheck(FilterExpr.java:108)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.compiler.LogicalExpr.typeCheck(LogicalExpr.java:131)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.compiler.If.typeCheck(If.java:85)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.compiler.SyntaxTreeNode.typeCheckContents(SyntaxTreeNode.java:484)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.compiler.ForEach.typeCheck(ForEach.java:83)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.compiler.SyntaxTreeNode.typeCheckContents(SyntaxTreeNode.java:484)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.compiler.Template.typeCheck(Template.java:291)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.compiler.SyntaxTreeNode.typeCheckContents(SyntaxTreeNode.java:484)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.compiler.Stylesheet.typeCheck(Stylesheet.java:654)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.compiler.Parser.createAST(Parser.java:405)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.compiler.XSLTC.compile(XSLTC.java:469)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.compiler.XSLTC.compile(XSLTC.java:557)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl.newTemplates(TransformerFactoryImpl.java:947)
    ... 70 more
```

in fact the error happens when trying to compare any two variables, not just these two

Comment: That's a runtime exception, not a compilation error.

Comment: You've tagged this XSLT 2.0, but you appear to be using XSLT 1.0.

Comment: @tgdavies I don't know Xalan/XSLTC internals but that stacktrace is pretty explicit that the error occurs during the call on newTemplates(), that is, while compiling the stylesheet. What is odd though is that a failure found during type checking should result in a stack trace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a string that you have, just use `starts-with($lowerEmail, $otherVar)` for your boolean expression. In XPath 1, a predicate works on node(set)s.

Comment: thank you, this was the issue. every single post i looked at had either a . or text() in the first parameter.

Comment: It's a great idea to try and understand the language spec, not just to copy and paste examples from the web.

Comment: To try and expand Martin's answer: Firstly, you are using XSLT 1.0 here, not 2.0 as stated. In XSLT 1.0, an expression of the form `$var[predicate]` is allowed only if `$var` is of type node-set. Although XSLT 1.0 has no type declarations on variables, Xalan has worked out that the value of the variable `$lowerEmail` will always be a string, because it is computed using the `translate()` function. It has worked this out during compilation of the stylesheet. It's a bit odd that this results in a crash with a stacktrace, but the error in your code is fairly clear.